# how to clone an Rc from a method that takes in &self

Tags: rust, self, reference-counting, cyclic-reference, refcell

I have a struct `Region` which contains `[Option<Rc<RefCell<Region>>>; 2]` as its `subregions` and `Option<Weak<RefCell<Region>>>` as its `container`. I am writing a method to insert a new `Region` between `self` and `self.container`, which requires me to clone the Rc to `self` to include in the newly created `Region` as one of its `subregions`. When `self.container` is `Some` this is possible because I can walk up to the container and then clone its `subregion` that matches `self`, but when `self` has `None` as its container, I do not know how to get a clone of the `Rc` of `self` from the `&mut self` that is passed into the method.

Here is some code to make it clearer.

```
struct Region {
    subregions: [Option<Rc<RefCell<Region>>>; 2],
    container: Option<Weak<RefCell<Region>>>,
}

impl Region {
    fn clone_from_container(&self) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<Region>>> {
        Some(Rc::clone(&self.container
                       .as_ref()?
                       .upgrade()
                       .unwrap()
                       .borrow()
                       .subregions[self.from()]
                       .as_ref()
                       .unwrap()))
    }

    pub fn insert_above(&mut self) -> Rc<RefCell<Region>> {
        let new = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Region {
            subregion: [self.clone_from_container(),None],
            container: self.container.clone(),
        }));
        self.replace(new.clone());
        self.container = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new.clone()));
        new
    }
}
```

In my actual code there are a few more functions, but these are just aliases for long method chains to unbox the `Rc`s and `RefCell`s to allow me to actually get at the data. I've tried to keep it to the important details only.

The methods I've excluded, `Region::replace` and `Region::from` are pretty simple and their implementation don't matter. `replace` walks up to the `container` and replaces the reference to `self` with the new region (very similar to `clone_from_container` but to mutate the `Region`), and `from` simply finds the index of the `Region` within its `container`'s `subregions` (0 or 1)

When setting the `subregion` of `new` within, I would like to be able to say something like `self.clone_from_container().or(Rc::clone(self))`, but obviously this isn't possible given the type that `self` is passed as.

I figure it may just be necessary to have this be a static factory function, rather than an instance method, so we can pass `self` with type `Rc<RefCell<Region>>`, but I also thought it may be possible to use `Rc::new_cyclic`; however, that function is somewhat confusing and I'm not quite sure how to employ it.

Comment: [`self` can be an `Rc<Self>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods) its the `RefCell` that makes it impossible.

Comment: Another option is to create a utility trait implemented for `Rc<RefCell<Region>>`, then you can use method calls as usual if you import the trait.

Comment: I'll look into the utility trait like you mentioned; if it doesn't make the code much more unreadable or anything I may do that, but otherwise I'll just have to change the method to a function that takes `Rc<RefCell<Region>>` as the param :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, I'm gonna say `Rc<Region>` instead of `Rc<RefCell<Region>>`

If I understood correctly, this is your situation:

```rust
let region = Region::new()
let rc = Rc::new(region)
```

And you have a method such as:

```rust
impl Region {
    fn my_function(&mut self) {
        // Here you want to somehow get a reference to `rc` (the Rc that contains this region)
    }
}
```

This is not possible, because `Region` doesn't know that it is inside an `Rc`. You have to somehow tell it that it is inside an `Rc`.

One possible solution is to not use `self`. For example:

```rust
impl Region {
    fn my_function(value: Rc<Self>) {
        // Now you have access to `rc`
    }
}
```

Another option, as PitaJ suggested, is to make a trait for `Rc<Region>`, in that case, `self` would be `Rc<Region>`, so you'd have access to `Rc`.

Comment: You don't need to make a trait for `Rc<Region>`, the `self` parameter can be an `Rc<Region>`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=c69aa402e96f10eb8e4b95b69a136237) (but that doesn't work with `RefCell`)

Answer (score 0):

There is this fancy [`Rc::new_cyclic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.new_cyclic) that allows you to store a `Weak` pointer into the object you are building.

Reusing the simplification by @CalcOPH from the other answer it would be something like:

```
struct Region {
    this: Weak<Self>,
    // other members
}
impl Region {
    fn new() -> Rc<Self> {
        Rc::new_cyclic(|this| {
            Region {
                this: this.clone(),
                // other members
            }
        })
    } 
    fn my_function(&mut self) -> Rc<Self> {
        // unwrap() cannot fail, unless called from `drop()`
        // because this object exists.
        self.this.upgrade().unwrap().clone()
    }
}
```

Naturally, it requires you to write the new a bit differently, but it may worth it.